# How to solve the com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException?

Tags: java, json, hibernate

I am getting the folowing exception when trying to JSON-ify the object:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )

I read about this exception in other posts and I think I need to use `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})` in one of my classes. But I could not understand what is the problem and which class should I annotate. Can somebody explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused because hibernate arquitecture, like spring, hibernate uses proxys to serve objects, and with javassist the arquitecture decorates the object with some stuff that are needed by the hibernate core and are 'transparent' to your 'user' code. Jackson BeanSerializer can see those stuff and try to convert them and he can not.

Comment: what is the solution?

Comment: I always use in that kind of situation @JsonIgnoreProperties. I don´t know if there is another way avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the same problem. And I solved it by using

```
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

By default Jackson will only work with fields that are either public, or have a public getter methods.Serializing an entity that has all fields private or package private will fail.

You can disable the serialization by

```
objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
```